# Validation loss never decreases during training

Tags: deep-learning, training-data, transformer-model, machine-translation, seq2seq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ3Ei.jpg)I encountered one perplexing situation: I trained a Transformer model for conditional music generation, finding the training loss decrease while the validation loss keeps increasing from the beginning, which is quite strange.

I attached a tensorboard screenshot for your reference. Here is the data allocation of about 2.7k songs: train:valid:test = 7:2:1.

I even try changing the learning rate from 0.01 to 0.00001, resulting nonetheless the same situation. On this above, shall I use more data for training or are there any other possible solutions regarding this?

Comment: That's because your model is overfitting. Do you use any regularization techniques?

Comment: Yes, I used L2 regularization by setting weight_decay to 0.9. Still the same situation. I was wondering if the dataset is not large enough to make a complex model converge.